# Unable to import outputSchema from pigutil in python

Tags: python, pig-udf

This might be pretty basic question, i am new to pig and python area.
I am trying to import outputSchema from pigutil.

The outputSchema is used as following inside the python UDF :-

```
 @outputSchema('HistorySchema:bag{t:(SomeKey:int,ScdColumnNew:chararray,ScdColumnOld:int, activeFlag:chararray, EndDate:int, ChangeDate:int)}')
```

I am getting below error while trying to run and check on **Python command line editor**.

```
NameError: name 'outputSchema' is not defined
```

Once imported using the statement

```
from pigutil import outputSchema
```

Getting below error :-

```
ImportError: No module named org.apache.pig
```

What i am trying to achieve here is to write a UDF that would return 2 tuple from a single tuple in Pig. I have tried the approach to use two different generate statements and then do the union of both, but its performance heavy, hence going for the UDF.

Answer (score 0):

from pig_util import outputSchema

http://help.mortardata.com/technologies/pig/writing_python_udfs#toc_4UsingtheoutputSchemaDecoratorinPython